# Paperjs Group with PointText

Tags: javascript, vector, paperjs

I am trying to achieve a simple thing - I need a text within a circle (or different path shape) and treat them as a single "object". I thought that the `Group` object is the best solution for it. However, the paperjs behaves strange once I add a `PointText` into the group.

Please check this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).

If there is the text in the group

```
new Group([circle, text])
```

The result of clicking on the circle is only

```
event.item = Group @83
```

But if you do not add the text into the group, then the result is

```
event.item = Group @87
hit2.item = Group @87
```

So for whatever reason if there is a text in the group, then the result of hitTest is null.

Do you see, please, if there is a bug in my code or in the library itself?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this is weird and it looks like a bug in the library itself.
Could you please post it as a new issue here: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues, we'll try to fix it as soon as possible.

As a workaround, if you know that your text is contained within the other shape, you could simply do the hit testing on the other shape directly rather than on the group:

```js
var hit2 = circle.hitTest(event.point);
```

---

#### Edit

Actually, I noticed that this also work if you call the hit testing on the group directly:

```js
var hit2 = group.hitTest(event.point);
```